# NSError double pointers in Parse iOS API

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

The Parse API has some asynchronous methods that take target and selector arguments. Some of them specify an (NSError **) argument in the signature for the selector. For example, the PF User class has a method `- (void)signUpInBackgroundWithTarget:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector` and the documentation says the selector should have this signature `(void)callbackWithResult:(NSNumber *)result error:(NSError **)error`. I am having trouble using the NSError object in my implementation.

In my code I do this:

```
- (void)signup
{
    PFUser *newUser = [PFUser user];
    [newUser setUsername:@"something"];
    [newUser setEmail:@"test@test.com"];
    [newUser setPassword:@"12345"];
    [newUser signUpInBackgroundWithTarget:self selector:@selector(signupDiDFinishWithResult:(NSNumber *)result error:(NSError **)error)];
}

- (void)signupDiDFinishWithResult:(NSNumber *)result error:(NSError **)error)
{
    if (error) {
        NSError *myError = *error;
        NSLog(@"Error code: %d", [myError code]);
        // I have also tried [*error code];
    }
}
```

When I run this and get to `[myError code]` line I get `+[NSError code]: Unrecognized selector sent to class`. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong with this double pointer. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be a typo in the documentation. Did you try it with just `NSError *`?

Alternatively, use:

```
[newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error code: %d", [error code]);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Good point. I will give that a try. I assumed the documentation was correct because **error exists in multiple method descriptions. I'll test this right now.

Comment: ** is used when you want to provide a reference to an object that will be created and filled in by someone else. This is not the case when you receive this callback though so it seems strange.

Comment: You were correct. The documentation is wrong. Thank you for your help!